# How to compare the fit of two multilevel models which only differ in their fixed effects?

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, multilevel-analysis

I have two models looking like this, where just the fixed effects differ, but the random effects stay the same

```
# Example one
H2RS <- lmerTest::lmer(BZ ~ 1 + SV + ZP + (1 + SV | VPN), data = dailyfin) 
H4RSN <- lmerTest::lmer(BZ ~ 1 + SV + SV_DIFF + ZP + (1 + SV | VPN), data = dailyfin)
```

I want to know which of these models can describe/fits my data the best. How can I compare them (statistically)?

I have done other comparisons like

```
# Example two
H4RI <- lmerTest::lmer(BZ ~ 1 + SV + SV + ZP + (1 | VPN), data = dailyfin)
H4RSN <- lmerTest::lmer(BZ ~ 1 + SV + SV + ZP + (1 + SV| VPN), data = dailyfin)
```

with an anova

```
anova(H4RI, H4RSN, refit = FALSE)
```

This works as long as I have models with different numbers of random effect, as in example two.

But if I use this anova command for models with the same (number of) random effects as in example one the output says

```
       npar  AIC    BIC  logLik deviance Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
H2RS     7 3417 3452.1 -1701.5     3403                    
H4RSN    8 3419 3459.1 -1701.5     3403     0  1          1
```

which is an output that seems very weird to me because the interesting statistics are all 1 or 0 (and this always happens when comparing models with the same (number of) random effects).

I think the anova command does not lead to a valid result for comparisons of models like those in example one. Is there any way to compare models like them?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You say the fixed effects are the same in example one, but the fixed effects are in fact different (SV_DIFF is only present in the second fit of this example).

Comment: I like the parametric bootstrap approach implemented in `pbkrtest` via `pb-modcomp`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/pbkrtest.pdf

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand you are right. In example one the fixed effects are different and the random effects are the same. That was a mistake on my part. I fixed this inconsisteny.

Comment: @mkt Thank you. I followed your advice, but I didn't find information on how to interpret the output and how to report the values. Do you have any further websites etc. addressing this topic?

My Questions in detail are:
- Does a significant p-Value say the large or small model fits better?
- What parameter is meant by stat? Do I report it as a chi-square value? 

type         stat         df     p.value
LRT       5.017218 1 0.02509646 
PBtest    5.017218 NA 0.03296703

Comment: https://github.com/hojsgaard/pbkrtest

Comment: https://www.jstatsoft.org/htaccess.php?volume=059&type=i&issue=09&filename=paper

Comment: http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/pbkrtest/vignettes/pbkrtest-introduction.pdf

Comment: https://people.math.aau.dk/~sorenh/software/pbkrtest/index.html